# Using solr query on dspace to get items in specific collection

Tags: solr, dspace

I want to get list of items in specific collection.

This returns list of items `solr/search/select?q=search.resourcetype:2` and this one `solr/search/select?q=search.resourcetype:4` list of collections. But what i want is list of items in xyz collection.
what is the appropriate query to accomplish this.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If 17 is the collection id then add `&fq=location:l17`

```
solr/search/select?q=search.resourcetype:2&fq=location:l17
```

or `&fq=location.coll:17`

```
solr/search/select?q=search.resourcetype:2&fq=location.coll:17
```

for communities it's `&fq=location:m17` or `&fq=location.comm:17`

Comment: Thank you Antoine But it gives me same result for `solr/search/select?q=search.resourcetype:2&fq=location.coll:17`
and `solr/search/select?q=search.resourcetype:2&fq=location.coll:18 ` for different collection id.

Comment: on top of that i want this query implement for solr data-import  like this `<dataConfig>
  <document>
    <entity name="ind" processor="SolrEntityProcessor" url="http://myDomain:8080/solr/search" query="*:*&fq=search.resourcetype:2&fq=location.coll:1" fl="*,old_version:_version_"/>
  </document>
</dataConfig>`
and it says Data Config problem: The reference to entity "fq" must end with the ';' delimiter.

 but when i change the query to this it works ( brings everything)
`..
    query="*:*" fl="*,old_version:_version_"/>
  ..`

Comment: It's the & that must be escaped in xml: replace it by `&amp;` For your query maybe try `q=*:*&fq=search.resourcetype:2&fq=location.coll:17` ?

Comment: for the xml I tried that but i got an error with duplicate fq, And i changed on of the fq to q and leave & at all. Here it is `query="*:*" q="search.resourcetype:2" fq="location.coll:17"` . Thank you so much!